# Login and Register links in Layout

Tags: symfony, twig, sylius

Could someone please explain how I can add `“Log in”` and `“Register”` links to my Layout, that change to `‘Log Out’` and `‘My Account’` links, once the user has logged in?

I tried the following code, but it doesn’t work.

```
  {% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
    <a class="dark-grey-small bold" href="{{ path('sylius_shop_account_dashboard') }}">{{ 'sylius.ui.my_account'|trans }}</a>
    <a class="dark-grey-small bold" href="{{ path('sylius_shop_logout') }}">{{ 'sylius.ui.logout'|trans }}</a>
  {% else %}
    <a class="dark-grey-small bold" href="{{ path('sylius_shop_login') }}">{{ 'sylius.ui.login'|trans }}</a>
    <a class="dark-grey-small bold" href="{{ path('sylius_shop_register') }}">{{ 'sylius.ui.register'|trans }}</a>
  {% endif %}
```

My homepage action is as follows:

```
/*
 * This file is part of the Sylius package.
 *
 * (c) Paweł Jędrzejewski
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Sylius\Bundle\ShopBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

final class HomepageController
{
    /** @var EngineInterface */
    private $templatingEngine;

    public function __construct(EngineInterface $templatingEngine)
    {
        $this->templatingEngine = $templatingEngine;
    }

    public function indexAction(Request $request): Response
    {
        return $this->templatingEngine->renderResponse('@SyliusShop/Homepage/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there.

I believe your code will work if you assign the `ROLE_USER` when users register.

If you just want to check if user is logged in you can use:

```
{% if app.user %}
    # user is logged in
 {% else %}
    # user is not logged in
 {% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment @113408.

Unfortunately, like the suggestion from hoover_D above, where is_granted('ROLE_USER') only failed on the homepage, app.user failed on every page.

Comment: @NickChambers  what version of symfony are you using ?

Comment: This is what I have in my security.yml file.

https://github.com/BitBagCommerce/SyliusBDD/blob/master/app/config/security.yml

Comment: I'm using Sylius 1.4 and Symfony 4.2.3. Thanks.

Comment: @NickChambers would you mind using `{{ app.user }}` somewhere in your template for debug purposes just to make sure it doesn't return anything

Comment: Thanks @113408 I tried your suggestion and it didn't display anything on the homepage, but displayed the username (email address) on all other pages. Thanks for your suggestions, which I really appreciate.

Comment: @NickChambers maybe if you modify the question and add the code from your Homepage action it will help solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

I do use this `{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}`. For me check the ROLE_USER doens't always works. Note that is_granted uses the roles on the current session: so if you have a new role and didn't login/out it will not work. Notice that,as the docs says:

> IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY isn't a role, but it kind of acts like one, and
>   every user that has logged in will have this

Comment: Thanks very much for this @hoover_D

I tried your suggestion, but where is_granted('ROLE_USER') only failed on the homepage, is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') failed on every page.

I'm wondering if it might be due to an entry within my security.yml file, but the character limit on these posts prevents me from posting the entry in question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks to @hoover_D and @113408 for your replies, but after a lot of trial and error, I managed to solve it.

Within my security.yml file, I changed

`sylius.security.shop_regex: '^/(?!admin|api/.*|api$|media/.*)[^/]++'`

to

`sylius.security.shop_regex: '/'`

and now is_granted('ROLE_USER') works on every page, including the home page.